# How do I use putenv() to update existing environment variable?

Tags: php, environment-variables, getenv

*Edit: as far as I can tell, my question is because of a defect in PHP. I've copied this question to the PHP bug tracker here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74143 and plan to try and implement a fix.*

---

The putenv function sets the value of an environment variable. According to the manual, putenv returns true on success, false on failure.

However, I'm finding that the putenv function sometimes returns true without updating the environment variable for the current session.

To reproduce this issue, set an environment variable in a webserver using PHP FPM, by using the fastcgi_param directive. This is incredibly useful, as it allows setting environment variables in isolation to other hosts on the same server.

Example nginx.conf:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   TESTVAR_ENV     old-value;
        include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

Example test.php:

```
var_dump(getenv("TESTVAR_ENV"));
var_dump(putenv("TESTVAR_ENV=new-value"));
var_dump(getenv("TESTVAR_ENV"));
```

Output of test.php:

```
string(12) "old-value"
bool(true)
string(12) "old-value"
```

As you can see:

1. the existing value is read by getenv successfully,
2. the putenv function returns true, indicating success,
3. the new value is not actually set, which is incredibly confusing.

Am I misunderstanding what the purpose of the putenv function is? Is there some missing documentation on the setenv manual page? How do I use putenv() to update existing environment variable?

Comment: I've not seen this behaviour myself. Have you tried removing the old value first? `putenv("TESTVAR_ENV")` should clear the value, or maybe try using `$_SERVER` instead?

Comment: Actually, just tested this with Nginx and PHP-FPM, instead of CLI and I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: Do you think this is a bug with PHP, or PHP-FPM?

Comment: Well, I just tried it in Apache with mod_php and get the same behaviour.

Comment: Using `$_SERVER` works as expected.

Comment: The [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) page says ```Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.```  I can't convince myself that "failing" to change the value of an existing var is anything other than a failure...  making this a php defect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is interesting. After investigating i found that there's an [undocumented parameter](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.1.2/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4040) for `getenv()`.

Calling `putenv("TESTVAR_ENV=new-value")` followed by `getenv("TESTVAR_ENV", true)` returns `new-value` as expected. However `getenv("TESTVAR_ENV", true)` returns false when called without explicitly setting the value first.

Reading from the [source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.1.2/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4059) it seems that if *local_only* is set to false (the default), the value is fetched using `sapi_getenv`, whereas with *local_only* set to true the native `getenv` is used.

Furthermore, if `sapi_getenv` doesn't return a value, then `getenv` is called as a fallback. Meaning if you don't set `TESTVAR_ENV` in nginx/Apache configuration at all, `putenv`/`getenv` works as expected.

So to recap:

- `getenv(name)` searches from SAPI's (php-fpm) internal environment table, and fallbacks to OS's environment if variable is not set.
- `getenv(name, true)` searches only from OS's environment, which doesn't necessarily (depending on the SAPI) contain variables registered in the web server's configuration.
- `putenv()` always only updates OS's environment.

I used the following to test this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

dump_env();
echo 'getenv("TESTVAR_ENV") => ' .
    var_export(getenv("TESTVAR_ENV"), true) . "\n";
echo 'getenv("TESTVAR_ENV", true) => ' .
    var_export(getenv("TESTVAR_ENV", true), true) . "\n";
echo "-----------\n";
echo 'putenv("TESTVAR_ENV=new-value") => ' . 
    var_export(putenv("TESTVAR_ENV=new-value"), true) . "\n";
dump_env();
echo 'getenv("TESTVAR_ENV") => ' .
    var_export(getenv("TESTVAR_ENV"), true) . "\n";
echo 'getenv("TESTVAR_ENV", true) => ' .
    var_export(getenv("TESTVAR_ENV", true), true) . "\n";

function dump_env() {
    echo "--- env ---\n" . `env` . "-----------\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input on this. I've updated the documentation on php.net to reflect this behaviour, although I still think the functionality could be improved somewhat.

Comment: passing 'true' to `getenv` gives this error in apache/error_log: `PHP Warning:  getenv() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new variable into `$_ENV` or `$_SERVER` directly:

```
/**
 * Return specified environment variable set in `.env` file
 */
function env(string $varname = '')
{
    return $varname ? $_ENV[$varname] : $_ENV;
}

/**
 * Set environment variable
 */
function setenv(string $key, string $value)
{
    return $_ENV[$key] = $value;
}

setenv("APP_ROOT_DIR", "YOUR_APPLICATION_ROOT_DIR"); // Sets the variable into $_ENV

echo env("APP_ROOT_DIR"); // Returns specified variable

print_r(env()); // Return the whole $_ENV array
```

**Or:**
You can even use this package: [PHP Environment variables manager (php dotenv)](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)